# Override the IIdentity property of User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iidentity

I have developed a simple `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` for my MVC project and I would like to override the `User` and `User.Identity` to return the value with the right type

Here is my custom Identity:

```
public class MyIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public MyIdentity(string name, string authenticationType, bool isAuthenticated, Guid userId)
    {
        Name = name;
        AuthenticationType = authenticationType;
        IsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    #region IIdentity
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string AuthenticationType { get; private set; }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    public Guid UserId { get; private set; }
}
```

Here is my custom Principal:

```
public class MyPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    public MyPrincipal(IIdentity identity)
    {
        Identity = identity;
    }


    #region IPrincipal
    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Here is my custom controller, I successfully updated the `User` property to return my custom principal type:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected new virtual MyPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext == null ? null : HttpContext.User as MyPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

How can I do it the same way for `User.Identity` to return my custom identity type?

Comment: where are you setting your custom principal on HttpContext?

Comment: In my global.asax.cs Application_AuthenticateRequest method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly implement `IPrincipal` in your `MyPrincipal`class, and add your own `Identity` property of type `MyIdentity`.

```
public class MyPrincipal : IPrincipal 
{
    public MyPrincipal(MyIdentity identity)
    {
        Identity = identity;

    }

    public MyIdentity Identity {get; private set; }

    IIdentity IPrincipal.Identity { get { return this.Identity; } }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please double check your code, I don't see how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: I think i understand this line: "IIdentity IPrincipal.Identity { get { return this.Identity; } }", but this is the first time I see something like that. Can you explain how to interpret it? TIA

Comment: Swell `IPrincipal.Identity` is an explicit implementation of the interface member (google for "explicit interface implementation" for more info).  The interface member needs to be implemented explicitly to avoid it conflicting with your custom member Identity which has a different type (MyIdentity vs IIdentity).  The implementation simply returns the MyIdentity instance (which is automatically cast to IIdentity).

Answer (score 1):

You're asking something that cannot be done without an explicit cast

```
public class MyClass
{
    private SomeThing x;
    public ISomeThing X { get { return x; } }
}
```

When you call `MyClass.X`, you're going to get an `ISomeThing`, not a `SomeThing`. You can do an explicit cast, but that's a bit clumsy.

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
SomeThing someThing = (SomeThing)(myClass.X);
```

Ideally, the value you store for `IPrincipal.Name` will be unique. If "jdoe" is not unique in your application, then your `IPrincipal.Name` property would be better if it stored the user ID. In your case, that appears to be a GUID.

Comment: I want to do an explicit cast like for MyPrincipal User. I want to cast the return type of User.Identity to MyIdentity